# Dpytest error : discord.app_commands.errors.MissingApplicationID

Tags: python, discord, pytest

I have implemented slash commands using discord.py and hybrid commands. They all are working well. I load my slash commands using this piece of code:

```
@bot.event
async def setup_hook():
    """Hooking setup."""
    print(f"{bot.user} is now running!")
    for cog in settings.COGS_LIST:
        await bot.load_extension(cog)
        print(f"Loaded Cog: {cog}")
        
    # loading command tree to update command list for auto-completion.
    await bot.tree.sync()

    for command in bot.tree.walk_commands():
        print('Loaded commands: ', command.name)
```

But when I add bot.tree.sync() in my test cases using dpytest like this:

```
@pytest_asyncio.fixture  # type: ignore
async def bot() -> AsyncGenerator[commands.Bot, None]:
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    intents.message_content = True
    b = commands.Bot(
        command_prefix=settings.DISCORD_COMMAND_PREFIX,
        intents=intents,
        strip_after_prefix=True,
        help_command=None,
    )

    @b.event
    async def setup_hook():  # type: ignore
        """Hooking setup."""
        print(f"{b.user} is now running!")
        for cog in settings.COGS_LIST:
            await b.load_extension(cog)
            print(f"Loaded Cog: {cog}")
        await b.tree.sync()
```

it gives me the following error:

> discord.app_commands.errors.MissingApplicationID: Client does not have
> an application_id set. Either the function was called before on_ready
> was called or application_id.

and if i remove sync commands from my test bot I get this error:

> asyncio.queues.QueueEmpty

Can anyone suggest how to solve this error?